# A print statement is speeding up my A * search?

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, search, printing

I'm creating an A* search at the moment ( [wiki page with pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) ) and I've been spending the last hour or so coming up with heuristic equations.  When I think I finally found a good one, I removed the print statement that was allowing me to see what states were being visited.  For some reason, that made my search go much much slower.  If I add the print back in, it becomes fast again.  What could possibly be going on?

I even tried changing what it prints.  No matter what I am printing (as long as it is 2 characters or more), the result is the same.

Some of the code:

I apologize beforehand for messy code, this is my first time working with something like this:

```
while(!toVisit.isEmpty()){//toVisit is a set of states that need to be visited
    int f = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    State temp;
        State visiting = new State();
        Iterator<State> it = toVisit.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){//find state with smallest f value
            temp = it.next();
            if(temp.getF() < f){
                f = temp.getF();
                visiting = temp;//should be state with smallest f by end of loop    
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Visiting: ");//THIS LINE HERE
//LINE THAT MAGICALY MAKES IT FAST ^^^^
        if(numConflicts(visiting.getList()) == 0){//checking if visiting state is the solution
                best = visiting.getList();//sets best answer
                return visiting;//ends algorithm
        }

    ........
```

info on toVisit and visiting.getList():

```
HashSet<State> toVisit = new HashSet<State>();//from Java.util

public ArrayList<Node> State.getList(){return list;}

Node is my own class. It only contains some coordinates
```

This consistently solves the problem in about 6 seconds.  If I change that line to print nothing or something shorter than about 2 characters, it takes anywhere from 20 to 70 seconds

Comment: Show some code, especially the lines around the printing.

Comment: What's the data type of `toVisit` and `State.getList()`?

Comment: How did you determine it is slower - maybe you are being hoodwinked by some buffering and as less output is generated, it *appears* slower. Did you measure the overall start-to-finish time, or just the perceived rate of progress?

Comment: @timrau added them to the question in an edit

Comment: @MarkSetchell 
  I start the timer, start the search, then end the timer as soon as the search is over.  Plus, the time is so dramatically different that I don't even need to time it to see it.

Comment: Is the "super fast" being [statistical significant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_significance)? Did you repeat the "experiment" 30+ times?